# getting wrong value with my gcd program

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I just wrote a program to calculate the gcd of two numbers. I tested it with the numbers 6 and 4. My program returns a result of 4 which is obviously wrong because the gcd for 6 and 4 is 2.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Zahlen {
  public static long gcd(long m, long n){
    m = Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for m"));
    n = Long.parseLong(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for n"));
    long tmp;
    while (n > 0) { 
      tmp = n;
      m = n;
      n = m;
      n = n%m;
    } // end of while
    return m;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print(Zahlen.gcd(6,4));
  }
}
```

Comment: `m = n;` and `n = m;`... This just sets `n = n;`

Comment: Also, why even use parameters if you are going to immediately override them?

Comment: Why is a simple debugging questions getting upvotes?

Comment: Why is this question getting close votes as "no longer can be reproduced or typographical error"?  This question is neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm code is incorrect.  The fragment

```
m = n;
n = m;
```

does nothing useful, and the value assigned to `tmp` isn't doing anything.

Get the remainder, then assign the value of `n` to `m`, then the remainder to `n`.  Use `tmp` for this purpose.

```
while (n > 0) {
    tmp = m%n;
    m = n;
    n = tmp;
}
```

Additionally, why do you ask the user for `m` and `n` values in the method `gcd` if you already have parameters?  Either don't ask in `gcd` and just use the parameters, or move the `JOptionPane` code to `main`, and pass the user's numbers into `gcd` there.

Comment: You must make sure though that `n <= m` before starting the loop.

Comment: @schwobaseggl If `n > m`, then the first loop will effectively swap the two numbers.

Comment: hmm.. `m%n == 0` for `n > m` => `n = 0` loop over, return `0`. Not?

Comment: @schwobaseggl No.  If `n > m`, then `m%n == m`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! :) Major brain malfunction on my part

Answer (score -1):

You can call below function (without using recursion) from main method:

```
public static int gcd(int n, int m){
    int gcd=1;
    int upto=n>m?m:n;

    for(int i=1;i<=upto;i++){
       if(n%i==0 && m%i==0){
            gcd=i;
        }
    }
   return gcd;
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with this answer ?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. I did it with int but casting it to long wouldn't be hard.

```
int m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for m"));
         int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for n"));
        int i =1;
        int gcd=1;
        while(m>n?i<=n:i<=m){
            if(m%i==0&& n%i==0){
                gcd=i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(gcd);}
```